# MVC/Razor Identity 2.0 - Where is error string for account already taken?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When a user is creating a new account and attempts to use a username that already exists, an error message is displayed by `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` that says:

> Name test@example.com is already taken.

I need to localize that string but cannot find it in the entire solution. Does anyone know where this string is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Identity 2,.0 is localizable via Nuget Packages:

```
Instal-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.XX
```

where XX is the desired culture (es, de, fr...)

There is no other way to do it.

Of course, you need to somewhat set the culture of your application: in web.config, programmatically, specified by the user's browser...

Comment: I am using Westwind.Globalization since it allows resource strings to be stored in a database. I do have customizations that set Culture and CultureUI. It seems weird there would be no other way.

Comment: I don't know Westwind Globalization. If it helps, install one of this packages for any culture, and then look for the satellite assemblies. Once you have them, you know where the strings are taken from. probably the tool you're using will allow you to import this satellite assembly.

Comment: This design is bad. A hebrewpackage is not available and I am stuck with the english messages. Is There any other way to customize these messages ?

Comment: @Yaron Levi, though I haven't yet addressed this in my project you may be interested in the Westwind Globalization package. You can install it via NuGet. It's free and really is a flexible solution for localizing strings. My reason for using it is that it will pull strings from a database instead of Resx - although it supports both.